# How to pass Datetime field value to the apex controller through VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:param name="JoBDate" value="{!b.job.Previous_State_1__c}" assignTo="{!completeddate}"/>

public Datetime completeddate{get;set;}
```

Value is not passing to the controller 'completeddate' variable.

the field Previous_State_1__c is of Date time.

Comment: what is the parent of the apex:param tag, outputlink,actionsupport,actionfunction?

Comment: I don't think there's enough code here; you probably trimmed too much. At first glance, this syntax looks right, but maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: @Rao Parent is actionsupport and only for datetime this issue is coming other string field are coming fine

Comment: @lokeshkumar can you post the VF page at least the part that is wrapping the datetime, I want to see why you would need a actionsupport